# How to show cell boundaries on a raster?

Tags: raster

I am trying to recreate a situation where each cell from a raster dataset has a black border as seen in this image. Any ideas?

[image: illustration of raster with visible cell boundaries]

Comment: It depends on the software.  For instance, in *Mathematica* you simply specify this as an option to the command to display the raster, whereas in ESRI software you will need a work-around.  Which software are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the Reply im using ESRI ArcInfo 9.3 as well as 10

Comment: Thanks for the help chaps In South Africa we have a saying - "As jy dom is moet jy kak".
Translated - "If your being stupid your going to battle".
I was using fishnet but I entered the wrong cell size. I eventually realised my mistake and have now got it right. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Probably the simplest way to achieve this is to create a fishnet (available in most GIS packages) and overlay this on your raster.  Be sure to align the fishnet to the raster cells by checking the raster's meta data.

Comment: After creating the fishnet, you'll want to [clip](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000004000000) it to the data area of the raster (so that the fishnet doesn't extend into the white areas of your sample image). You will need a vector of the data area's outline to do the clip, and to illustrate the data area with a thicker border (as shown in your image).

Comment: Hi There - I have trie fishnet but i cant seem to get it right? Any additional advice here?

Answer (score 1):

Another option, again using QGIS:

Generate a vector grid based on the raster, using the menu:

Vector/Research Tools/Vector grid

From there you can assign the properties of the grid to match the raster of your choice.

To clip the created grid to your raster use the menu item:

Vector/Geoprocessing Tools/Clip

This option avoids cells being joined together, as described in my other answer. However, this method is longer!

Answer (score 1):

Processing Toolbox → Vector Creation → Raster pixels to polygons

Answer (score 0):

Using QGIS you can convert the raster to polygon using the menu:

Raster/Conversion/Polygonize

This will create a fishnet as described by MappaGnosis.

One potential drawback I find is that the tool rounds to integer values, so if cells have the same number (after rounding) they're joined together.

Answer (score 0):

With QGIS it is possible to set up a `Contours` display in the rasters symbology settings, but building such contours is a rather slow procedure.

[image]__[image]