# How to show pixel boundaries of a given raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal-translate, grids-graticules, boundaries

The Norwegian Meterological Institute [provides historical weather data](https://thredds.met.no/thredds/catalog.html). I download one of these `.nc` files:

```
curl https://thredds.met.no/thredds/fileServer/ngcd/version_22.09/RR/type2/2022/08/NGCD_RR_type2_version_22.09_20220823.nc -o NGCD_RR_type2_version_22.09_20220823.nc
```

Then turn it into a `.tif` file using `gdal_translate`:

```
gdal_translate NGCD_RR_type2_version_22.09_20220823.nc NGCD_RR_type2_version_22.09_20220823.tif
```

I successfully open the `.tif` file in QGIS:[image]

If I zoom in to the edge, I see pixel boundaries:

[image]

I would however, like to see these boundaries even when I am not at the edge. [This thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76879/how-to-show-cell-boundaries-on-a-raster) is about a similar topic, but the [first answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/76883/191643) does not go into much detail, using the [second answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/76989/191643) I try:

```
Vector -> Research Tools -> Create Grid...
```

leading to:

[image]

which does not seem to be a place where I can just show a grid for a given raster, but rather create a grid from scratch.

**How could I visualize the boundaries of pixels of a given raster in QGIS?** The data is clearly there, the software knows where a pixel ends and the next starts, I just need to show it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to

- View - Decorations - Grid
- "Update intervals / Offsets from" click "Active Raster Layer"

Then click the Line symbol and adjust the symbol. I made the lines 0.06 wide
[image]